# Floating Image Interrupts Hover

Tags: css, wordpress, megamenu

I am having an issue with an image interrupting my hover state. I have my menu which is a mega menu drop down for wordpress. I then have the company's logo z-indexed above the menu so it covers part of the top menu and part of the drop down menu. When my mouse scrolls over the z-indexed logo, it breaks my hover state and closes the drop down menu. Is there a way to make the image essentially not register on hover?

Comment: please give a link so that we can take a look

Comment: http://www.eleven34studios.com/Hutson/5000-series/

Comment: Ooo, just noticed when you're not logged in it's pushed further down more than intended, have to fix that, it should be right on the line for the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add

```
  pointer-events: none;
```

to your .top-menu-logo. it works in modern browsers but this is not necessarly the html structure I would recommend.